# Issue in creating POST http.request with Node.js data are passed in FormValue instead of Body

Tags: node.js, http

i try to execute a http.request POST and my data are passed to FormValue and not in Body. 
It's my first experiment in Node.js http calls so I apologize if the question is trivial.
I passed the call to a servere and i got the data at the end of the code.

```
function doHttpApiCall(session,callback) {
    var http = require('http');   
    var isEndedOk;
    var outValue = '';
    var postData = JSON.stringify({
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            scope: 'OOB',
            my_id: 'my_id_value'
        });



    var postOptions = {
                host: 'dummyapisite.com',
                path: '/t/litf9-1571295453/post',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Content-Length': postData.length
                }
    };

   // Set up the request
   var post_req = http.request(postOptions, function(res) {
      var statusCode = res.statusCode;
      let error;
      if (statusCode !== 200) {
        error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                          `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
      }
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let rawData = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
          const  parsedData = rawData;
          if (error) {
                isEndedOk = false;
                console.error(error.message);
                console.error('Response Content=' + String(parsedData));
                res.resume();
          } else {
                isEndedOk = true;
                console.log('Response Content=' + String(parsedData));
          }         
          callback(session.attributes,
                callBack_doHttpApiCall(outValue, statusCode, session, callback, isEndedOk));
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e.message);
        }
      });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    });
    post_req.write(postData);
    post_req.end();
}
```

this is the result got by the server and the data are not in the right place.

```
{
   "Timestamp":"2019-10-17T13:53:52.941575Z",
   "Method":"POST",
   "RemoteAddr":"34.245.148.80",
   "ID":390940052,
   "Headers":{
      "Content-Length":[
         "118"
      ],
      "Content-Type":[
         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ],
      "Host":[
         "ptsv2.com"
      ],
      "X-Cloud-Trace-Context":[
         "deff20a349bfb409fab118aa361ebc54/925376340939905763"
      ],
      "X-Google-Apps-Metadata":[
         "domain=gmail.com,host=dummyapisite.com"
      ]
   },
   "FormValues":{
      "{\"body\":[{\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\",\"scope\":\"OOB\",\"my_id\":\"my_id_value\"}]}":[
         ""
      ]
   },
   "Body":"",
   "Files":null,
   "MultipartValues":null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending a `JSON` body, but the `Content-Type` you're sending is: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so change it to `application/json`

The server you're posting to, is putting the value in `FormValues` because you're telling them that you're sending a form (`x-www-form-urlencoded`)

```
var postOptions = {
    host: 'dummyapisite.com',
    path: '/t/litf9-1571295453/post',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok... well now data are in right place... but i still get 400 error cause i think the server is expeting x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: If the server is expecting `form-urlencoded` then you shouldn't post a `JSON`. You'll have to post info about the server you're posting, otherwise it's impossible to help you.